# Eclipse: Find call tree of a method

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> gives an output of all the methods that call directly the method I'm searching for. But how can I find the whole tree and not just the caller method. I want to output the whole call chain of a method (caller's caller etc), from the method it first started until the one I'm searching for.

Comment: Ctril + Shift + G searches for references, so it works on field also. But Ctrl + Shift + H search call hierarchy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select the method what you want and press `ctrl+Alt+H`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Ctrl + ALT + H` . Try it.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Ctrl + Alt + h` for `Open Call Hierarchy` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Upvoted but I will accept Rakesh's answer since it was faster by some seconds (just trying to be fair). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Or even better - try **Ctrl+Shift+L** and explore all the possibilities ;)

Comment: This shortcut opens Quick Text Search, which will not display a calling tree and also will bring results other than references to the method call.