# How to show the message send tree in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to view the message send hierarchy/tree from a given method. I see a lot of references for the "call tree" such as [Eclipse: Find call tree of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701320/eclipse-find-call-tree-of-a-method).
But would like to go in the other direction. In other words, not calls of the given method, but calls out of the given method (in tree form).

It's a feature I'm used to from another language. I've scanned Eclipse and searched for solutions, but no luck.

Comment: So, instead of showing where the method is called, show what methods the method calls?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hidden, but Eclipse let's you view the tree in both directions in the "Call Hierarchy".

- "Call Hierarchy":

  [image: Call Hierarchy]
- "Callee Hierarchy" :

  [image: Callee Hierarchy]